# visualizing properties attributes in the webadmin interface of neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have searched it over Internet but not able to find anything related to this.

Is there any way to visualize the properties attributes over the edges(links) in neo4j webadmin interface?

If yes then please guide me how can I do that?

If no then please suggest me that Is there any tool to do that or what can I do to get this in web interface.

Thanks

Comment: Not in the webadmin interface right now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114801/setting-caption-of-relationships-in-neo4j-2-0-0-browser

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to see the properties that are stored as part of relationships. There are many ways to do this in the Admin web UI.

For instance, in the Data Browser, enter the following Cypher query to see all the relationships in your DB, including their properties:

MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN r;

If you know the ID of the specific relationship you are interested in (let's say it is 92), use:

START r=rel(92) RETURN r;

I can only give the simplest answers. If you have a more complex question, please add more details.