# Setting caption of relationships in Neo4j 2.0.0. browser

Tags: css, graph, neo4j

In Neo4j 2.0.0 browser I'm trying to set styling of relationships using the .grass file.

my graph includes relations like

```
//Output :Affects Outcome
create (op1)-[:Affects {level:"Strong", direction:"Positive" }]->(oc1)
```

and my .grass file contains

```
relationship.Affects {
  color: blue;
  caption : '{type} {level} {direction}';
  shaft-width: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-color-external: #000000;
  text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
}
```

what I try to achieve is blue arrows (this works) with a caption that says  "Affects Strong Positive", but can't figure out how to set the caption. Can't find a list of attributes that can be set through .grass either.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, captions only apply to Nodes; relationships always display their type. Allowing a caption for relationships is something we'll take a look at as we evolve the grass styling.

Formalizing the grass specification and then enabling direct editing is on the roadmap.

Best,
Andreas